# Check if a directive contains a child directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to check if a directive contains another directive ? As far as I know in AngularJS there is nothing can do that, you can't require a child directive in the parent.

I have two directives one called `page-wrapper` and the other is `content-wrapper` like this :

```
<md-content page-wrapper>
    <profiles $router="::$$router" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <page-content>
        </page-content>
    </profil-liste>
</md-content>
```

What I'm trying to do is to check whether the  `page-wrapper` directive contains the `page-content` directive in it's children, if it doesn't then I should rise some exception.

I don't want to check if the `page-content` is inside it's parent, I already know how to that which doesn't fulfill my requirements.

## Edit :

Please take in consideration that I'm using `angular_1_router` so the `page-content` is not rendered in the phase where `page-wrapper` is compiled, this is how the `page-wrapper` looks in the link function :

```
innerHTML:"<profiles $router="::$$router" class="ng-scope"></profiles>"
```

So searching for the `page-content` in the DOM won't help with anything.

I also tried to delay it with the `$timeout` service :

```
function PageWrapperPostLink(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    $timeout(function(){
        console.log(element);
    });
}
```

Which didn't help, the page which contains `page-content` is not injected with the router yet.

Comment: possibly dig with the linked element: `element[0].lastChild`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Please check my edit.

Comment: delay it with $timeout ?

Comment: This feels like an XY Problem.  It's really not clear what *problem* you are trying to solve, and you are only asking about your potential *solution*.  However, this isn't a task that is common enough to understand what value it serves, or even make a guess as to the problem it is attempting to address.

Comment: @Claies I think my question was clear enough all I'm trying to do is to check if a directive contains another directive, since in angualrJs you can't require a directive in the parent directive, I'm looking for a solution

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I tried that it didn't help either

Comment: right, it isn't that the question isn't *clear*, it's more that what you are asking about isn't something standard to angular, for a reason;  there isn't any clearly obvious reason that having this information is useful, and you aren't really providing a clue as to why it would be in your case either.

Comment: If you describe the problem you are trying to solve, perhaps there is another way to accomplish the end goal, that doesn't require this level of framework depth.

Comment: @Claies Well, the problem I'm trying to solve, is all the pages that are injected with the router should contain the `page-content` defined if it's not the case I should rise some exception in the console so the developer will know that he forgot to use the `page-content` directive, the only solution I thought about is to check from the parent directive if it has `page-content` defined in it's DOM, the parent directive in this case is the `ng-outlet` (used by angular_1_route for the injection point) so I added another directive `page-wrapper` which will act as a parent directive in this case.

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to make the framework cross-check the developer's work?  I'm not an expert on that kind of activity, but it would seem like that's more a task for a Unit Test than an active page module....

Comment: @Claies what made me think of that, is when you require a parent directive inside a child directive, angularJS throws an error in the console that the parent directive is required, so then i wanted to implement the same

Comment: Well if it is for developing purpose you can set timeout to 1s-2s, but exclude this code in production build.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to happen if you don't find the `page-content` directive, but here is some sample code on how you could search from the `page-wrapper` directive to determine that situation.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('pageWrapper', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var pageContent = element[0].querySelector('page-content');
        if (pageContent) {
          console.log('found');
        } else {
          console.log('not found');
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div>
    <md-content page-wrapper>
      <profiles $router="::$$router" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
        <page-content>
        </page-content>
      </profiles>
    </md-content>
  </div>
</div>
```